# SwiftUI - Reload/Force the view to update/stop the animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that make the text slide from left to right when the text is too long for its context.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SlidingText: View {
    let geometryProxy: GeometryProxy
    @Binding var text: String
    let font: Font

    @State private var animateSliding: Bool = false
    private let slideDelay: Double = 3
    private let slideDuration: Double = 6

    private var isTextLargerThanView: Bool {
        if text.size(forWidth: geometryProxy.size.width, andFont: font).width < geometryProxy.size.width {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
            VStack(content: {
                Text(text)
                    .font(self.font)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            })
                .id("SlidingText-Animation")
                .fixedSize()
                .animation(isTextLargerThanView ? Animation.linear(duration: slideDuration).delay(slideDelay).repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : nil)
                .frame(width: geometryProxy.size.width,
                       alignment: isTextLargerThanView ? (animateSliding ? .trailing : .leading) : .center)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    self.animateSliding.toggle()
                })
        })
            .clipped()
    }
}
```

The problem here is, if I have a text that was too long, it will do the correct animation, but then when I change the text during the animation, it doesn't take in consideration the new size and the `isTextLargerThanView` is ignored. I also tried a `didSet` for my `@Binding var text: String`, it doesn't work either.

I am not really sure how to handle this case here, I tried to use custom Binders but didn't work. I know in iOS 14 there will be a `onUpdate(on: _)` function but I need it to work on iOS 13 too.

Do you have an idea of what I could do to update my text and be able to update the `isTextLargerThanView`?

Thank you for any future help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code. Maybe you can try to make it reactive like this:

```
@Binding var text: String {
        didSet {
            isTextLargerThanView = (text.size(forWidth: geometryProxy.size.width, andFont: font).width > geometryProxy.size.width)
        }
    }
    
...

@State private var isTextLargerThanView = false
```

Comment: I tried that but the `didSet` is no called. let me try again! (it is written in my original post)

Comment: You can run it by calling it like this, replace the font with a system one: GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
                    SlidingText(geometryProxy: geometry,
                                text: self.$playerViewModel.seasonByline,
                                font: .custom("FoundersGrotesk-RegularRegular", size: 15))
                })
                    .frame(height: 20)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you had tried this. I actually did run it with other font, but the screen is blank. So I might miss sth.